# When should I say "of London" instead of "from London"?

Tags: prepositions

When should I say "of London" instead of "from London"?

For example:

> 1. Twinings of London
> 2. Twinings from London

Answer (score 2):

'Of' has the connotation of belonging, of being an integral part, and in the context you have used it, of a proud demographic heritage. You would use 'of' like you have in your example, if you wanted to convey this sense of proud demographic heritage.

'from' carries less weight, and in the context you have used it simply means this is where the object is based / originated. You would use 'from' if you wanted to convey a more literal statement regarding the source of an objects origin.